# Binding an Image to the GroupStyle Datatemplate in a grouped Listview (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I would like to be able to bind an image based on the group name for a grouped listview in C# WPF.

For example, if I have 3 different groups in a single listview, the listview will group items based on the group they belong to, but I would also like to add an image into the group header based on the group name, not just the text of the group.

Here is the group styling definition

```xml
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource collectionViewSource}}" Width="{Binding EventListWidth}" Height="{Binding EventListHeight}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Food" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Food}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Calories" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Calories}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>

    <ListView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16" Foreground="Gray"/>
             Here->     <Image Source={Bind to a specific image based on the group name} />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ListView.GroupStyle>
</ListView>
```

Here is the collection view source definition

```xml
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="collectionViewSource" Source="{Binding MyBinding}">
    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Grouping" />
    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

So for example:

Group one's header will contain the text "Ice cream" and have an image of an ice cream cone.

Group two's header will contain the text "French Fries" and have an image of fries

Group three's header will contain the text "Soda" and have an image of a soda can

Any ideas? Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Figured it out.

I simply used a converter method to assign an Image source underneath the textblock based on the groups text.

```
<ListView.GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle>
                            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <Image Source="{Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource EventTypeToImage}}" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource EventTypeToText}}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16" Foreground="Gray"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        </GroupStyle>
                    </ListView.GroupStyle>
```